# Way to check were you redirected either from a main page or subpage

Tags: javascript, html

I try to execute javascript animation only when a user gets redirected from the main page, not a subpage.

I thought document.referrer.match() might do the thing, but I've probably messed up with match() parameters.

Also, I'm running it on local server and *iglakowe.com* is the main page address.

```js
const ref = document.referrer.match(/iglakowe.com/)
if (ref != null){
 document.getElementById("bg").style.opacity = 0;
}
```

Comment: It's not too clear what you're asking. The above snippet should check if the url of the page currently displayed in the browser is a subdomain e.g. https://sub.iglakowe.com or https://iglakowe.com ?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I meant iglakowe.com/something.html as a subdomain. Sorry.
I fixed the title.

Comment: Why not just have the redirection send in a query string param, based on the presence of which you can then run the animation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with some string manipulations.
First get the document referrer

```
const ref = document.referrer;
```

This might return something like **https://stackoverflow.com/somePage.html**

strip the // from the returned string

```
const ref = document.referrer.replace("//","");
```

ref will be **https:stackoverflow.com/somePage.html**

Now simply search for an occurence of the **/** char

```
 const ref = document.referrer.replace("//","").indexOf("/");
```

ref is a positive integer now because there is a **/** inside the string which essentially means the **/** is following something like a folder or filename.

If it's **-1** it's almost safe to say that the referer was the main page.

```
const ref = document.referrer.replace("//","").indexOf("/");
if (ref>-1){
 document.getElementById("bg").style.opacity = 0;
}
```

Comment: It looks like document.referrer always returns "http://-iglakowe.com-/". That means checking for indexOf("/") won't work because on the main page and subpage there'll be always "/" at the end. 
Based on your answer I did: document.referrer.replace("http://-iglakowe.com-/","");
and: if (ref===""){...}.
Now it works!

Comment: I don't really know why the domain name is surrounded by minus signs but I'm glad you could figure out something based on my answer!